# Stripe token in a modal form is always an empty string

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, stripe-payments

**EDIT:**
Everything works when I use my transactions.js.coffee on a non-modal version of the form. Something about handling the form as `xhr` is preventing `Stripe.createToken` from accessing the `f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token`. or maybe the `jQuery` object is being created before the modal exists, so `setupForm()` fails silently because it can't find `$("#new_transaction_button")` because that element is in the modal, and thus hidden when the script runs? Maybe `:attr_accessor :stripe_card_token` doesn't work in the modal?

I'm trying to allow users to enter credit card details in a modal window.
I have combed through this and cannot figure out why Stripe keeps setting the token as an empty string `Stripe error while creating customer: Empty string given for card.`

I suspect this is an issue with the way the form is getting passed around by jquery.

Here is my `transactions.js.coffee` file:

```
jQuery ->
    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))  
    transaction.setupForm()

transaction =
    setupForm: ->
        $("#new_transaction_button").click ->
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
            transaction.processCard()
            valuesToSubmit = $("#new_transaction").serialize()
            $("#new_transaction_modal").modal "hide"
            .ajax(
                url: "/posts"
                data: valuesToSubmit
                type: "POST"
            ).success (data, status) ->

            false

    processCard: ->
        card =
            number: $('#card_number').val()
            cvc: $('#card_code').val()
            exp_month: $('#card_month').val()
            exp_year: $('#card_year').val()
        Stripe.createToken(card, transaction.handleStripeResponse)

    handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
        if status == 200
            $('#transaction_stripe_card_token').val("test")
            $('#new_transaction')[0].submit()
        else
            alert(response.error.message)
```

in the `handleStripeResponse` function above, I've set the `#transaction_stripe_card_token.val()` as "test" to demonstrate that it seems to me the function `handleStripeResponse` is not even being called, because otherwise the console would output `Stripe error while creating customer: string "test" given for card.`. Is this correct? If it is, why isn't `handleStripeResponse` getting called? Is it because of the way a modal form is handled by my controller?

**transactions_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    if @post = Post.where(:id => flash[:the_post_id]).first
    #@price = @post.price
      @tier_id = @post.tier_id
      @amount = @tier_id*100
    else
      @amount = 1000
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      #non-user encountered form and entered credit details AND password- signing up and paying
      if !current_user && params[:password].present?        
        @user = User.new(:email => params[:transaction][:email], :password => params[:password])
        @transaction = @user.transactions.new(params[:transaction].merge(:price => @amount))
        @transaction.save_customer(@user)
        if @transaction.save && @user.save
          @user.charge_as_customer(@amount)
          #sign_in @user
          format.js { render }
          format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @transaction, status: :created, location: @transaction }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
```

**The Modal Credit Card Form: (whitespace/indentation is correct in production. having trouble copy/pasting)**

```
= simple_form_for @transaction, :validate => true, :remote => true, :form => { "data-type" => "json" } do |f|
  %div.modal-header
    %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
    - if @transaction.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %h2= "#{pluralize(@transaction.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this transaction from being saved:"
        %ul
          - @transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg

  %div.modal-body
    =hidden_field_tag :post_id

    = f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token

%div.row-fluid
  %div
    = label_tag :credit_card_number, nil, :id => "credit_label"
    = text_field_tag :credit_card_number,nil, :class=>"credit-number span12", :id => "card_number"
%div.row-fluid
  %div.span4
    = label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
    = select_month nil, {:add_month_numbers => true}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_month"}
    = select_year nil, {:start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year+15}, {:name => nil, :id => "card_year"}
  %div.span3
  %div.span2.credit-cvv
    = label_tag :cvv, "CVV"
    = text_field_tag :cvv, nil, :class=>"credit-cvv input-block-level", :id => "card_code"
%div.row-fluid
  =f.label :email
  =f.text_field :email, :validate => true
-unless current_user
  %div.row-fluid
    =label_tag :password
    =text_field_tag :password, params[:password]
  %div.modal-footer
    = f.button :submit, name: 'Get It', class: "btn-primary", id: "new_transaction_button"
```

And, to be thorough, here is my `save_customer` method for transactions:

```
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_customer(user)
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create( :description => email, :card => stripe_card_token)
      user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
      save!
    end
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Egads, Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
```

Can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks amigos.

Comment: Should the line in your coffeescript read `Stripe.createToken(card, transaction.handleStripeResponse)` instead? You've got `subscription.handleStripeResponse`, but I doesn't look like `subscription` is defined in what you've shared.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, that was a copy paste problem. copied old version. unfortunately, that's not the issue.

Comment: I can get everything to work when the form for the credit card details is not rendered in a modal window. For some reason it seems that I can't use `Stripe.createToken` to set the value of a `f.hidden_field` in my modal form.

Comment: @Brian, I'm curious if you ever figured this out. I have the same problem right now.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out in time so just stopped using a modal. Had to admit defeat. Would love to hear about it if you ever figure it out. Godspeed